# UITableView with card cards and list inside - iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to create a custom `UITableView` to show cards with my items inside, something like this:

[image: Custom UITableView with cards]

I have already a class CardView to create my cards with a shadow, but I didn't succeed to use it properly to obtain what I'm looking for.

Maybe the best way to do that is to customise sections and to apply my CardView on them.

Can you help me with that?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you add some code to show what you've tried?

Comment: You can add shadow image as background of cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use UITableview inside tableviewcell.

1.Create UITableView1->UITableviewCell1->UIView->UITableView2->UITableviewCell2

2.Set UITableview2 delegates in UITableviewCell1

3.Reload UITableView2 inside UITableView1 cellforRow

step 2
Inside UITableviewCell1
`override func awakeFromNib() {
        //UITableView2 Delegates
        self.tableView2.delegate = self
        self.tableView2.dataSource = self
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }`

Comment: Can you detail the second step: Set UITableviewCell2 delegates in UITableviewCell1? Thanks

Comment: sorry Set UITableview2 delegates in UITableviewCell1'override func awakeFromNib() {
        //TableView Delegates
        self.tableView2.delegate = self
        self.tableView2.dataSource = self
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }'

Answer (score 1):

For this issue, just add the `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method with the following code (a simple copy/paste should work), it should work for grouped tables too. I commented where you should set the width and color of the border.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(tintColor)]) {
        CGFloat cornerRadius = 5.f;
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor;
        CAShapeLayer *layer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
        CGMutablePathRef pathRef = CGPathCreateMutable();
        CGRect bounds = CGRectInset(cell.bounds, 10, 0);
        BOOL addLine = NO;
        if (indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.row == [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section]-1) {
            CGPathAddRoundedRect(pathRef, nil, bounds, cornerRadius, cornerRadius);
        } else if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            CGPathMoveToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMinX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds));
            CGPathAddArcToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMinX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds), CGRectGetMidX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds), cornerRadius);
            CGPathAddArcToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds), CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMidY(bounds), cornerRadius);
            CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds));
            addLine = YES;
        } else if (indexPath.row == [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section]-1) {
            CGPathMoveToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMinX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds));
            CGPathAddArcToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMinX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds), CGRectGetMidX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds), cornerRadius);
            CGPathAddArcToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds), CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMidY(bounds), cornerRadius);
            CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds));
        } else {
            CGPathAddRect(pathRef, nil, bounds);
            addLine = YES;
        }
        layer.path = pathRef;
        CFRelease(pathRef);
        //set the border color
        layer.strokeColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
        //set the border width
        layer.lineWidth = 1;
        layer.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.f alpha:1.0f].CGColor;


        if (addLine == YES) {
            CALayer *lineLayer = [[CALayer alloc] init];
            CGFloat lineHeight = (1.f / [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
            lineLayer.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(bounds), bounds.size.height-lineHeight, bounds.size.width, lineHeight);
            lineLayer.backgroundColor = tableView.separatorColor.CGColor;
            [layer addSublayer:lineLayer];
        }

        UIView *testView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:bounds];
        [testView.layer insertSublayer:layer atIndex:0];
        testView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor;
        cell.backgroundView = testView;
    }
}
```

Also, remember to set the separator property of the table to none in the Interface Builder, (it's by default to single line), if you are creating the table programmatically you should set the property like this

```
tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Code:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwYZPQSG7kikbVpUZklGSWFwMTA/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score -1):

Use an UICollectionView and see the following tutorial which does exactly what you want:

http://www.phillfarrugia.com/2017/06/19/rebuilding-the-new-app-store-app-today-view/